# Hovering issue with Jquery

Tags: jquery, progressive

Say I have 3 div elements with one class, hovering one of them I want the background of the inner element to change to a red. I tryed to add an ID for each element like this:

```
<div class="content"><div class="yellow_hover"></div></div>
<div class="content"><div class="yellow_hover"></div></div>
<div class="content"><div class="yellow_hover"></div></div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.content').each(function(i, div) {
div.id="div" + (i+1);
});
```

Result

```
<div class="content" id="div1"></div>
<div class="content" id="div2"></div>
<div class="content" id="div3"></div>
```

Now I need something like this, yeah I know... I'm lost:

```
$(div+i).hover(function() {
   $('.yellow_hover').css('background-color','#FF9900');
});
```

Comment: Is that really the result? Dies the .yellow_hover DIV disappear?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need js for this, in your css set the following rule:

```
.content:hover .yellow_hover {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/87pghLm2/2)

Comment: This CSS will change the background color of both divs. Inside the content div is a little area (yellow_hover div). Hovering the bigger div must change the color of the yellow_hover.

Comment: You are right, sorry I saw ".content: hover .yellow: hover", to many hours working ...

Answer (score 1):

You need not to add `id` to the div, remove that code. try below code for hovering

```
$('.content').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('.yellow_hover').css('background-color','#FF9900');
}, function(){
   $(this).find('.yellow_hover').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tk236ez4/2/)**

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer doing this via css?

Comment: So easy ? just like that. Thanks

Comment: yes, it is easy.. first function of hover on and second for hover off

Comment: @PatsyIssa, yeah CSS3 is also one of the option for manipulating DOM or animation.

Answer (score 1):

Give the element a class like "yellow_box"

Jquery

```
$(".yellow_box").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "yellow_hover" );
  }, function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "yellow_hover" );
 }
);
```

When we hover a div, we add a class (yellow_hover)

See jquery documentation for more information
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

In JS you need to done like that :

```
$('body').on('hover','[id^="div"]',function() {
   $('[id^="div"]').removeAttr( "background-color" );
   $(this).css('background-color','#FF9900');
});
```